Inverse and Composition of Bisimulations
Exercise 63 of Rutten's The Method of Coalgebra: exercises in coinduction asks us to prove that "the collection of all bisimulation relations between two given stream systems is closed under (i) arbitrary unions and intersections, (ii) inverse, and (iii) composition (of composable relations)".
For background, a stream system $(S, \langle o_S, tr_S \rangle)$ consists of a set $S$ and a function $\langle o_S, tr_S \rangle: S \to A \times S$ for some set $A$, and a bisimulation of stream systems $(S, \langle o_S, tr_S \rangle)$ and $(T, \langle o_T, tr_T \rangle)$ is a relation $R \subseteq (S,T)$ such that for all $(s,t)\in R$, $o_S(s)=o_T(t)$ and $(tr_S(s), tr_T(t)) \in R$.
Given two bisimulations $R_1$ and $R_2$, their union $R_1 \cup R_2$ and intersection $R_1 \cap R_2$ make sense, but I have no idea what is meant by inverse and composition.
The only thing I can think of for the inverse of $R$ is $\{(s,t) | (s,t) \not\in R\}$ but I'm not sure that's right, and I have no idea how to compose two relations to get another other than by union and intersection. Can anyone clarify?

The definitions of some operations on relations can be found here. That source calls the inverse the "converse" instead, but it's the same thing.
Given a relation $R \subseteq A \times B$, the inverse of $R$ is the subset of $B \times A$ given by $R^{-1} = \{(b, a) \mid (a, b) \in R\}$.
Given relations $R \subseteq A \times B$ and $S \subseteq B \times C$, the composition of $R$ and $S$ is $S \circ R = \{(a, c) \mid \exists b \in B, (a, b) \in R \text{ and } (b, c) \in S\}$.
These two operations restrict to the familiar notions of the inverse of a function (when it exists) and the composition of two functions. In the latter case, the element $b$ that has to exist is necessarily unique.
